# Android contact number format

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to retrieve the contacts numbers in the phone and i have successfully done that, however the formatting is different per contact.

the code i use to retreive the contact information is

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        System.out.println("Phone Number " + phoneNumber);
```

The output is

> Phone Number (555) 555-5555
>
> Phone Number  5555555555

I dont understand why this is the case. In the emulator i am using i added the contacts the exact same way. Name and a mobile number. Im not sure why they are different

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, that is because of locale settings of android you are using.
I don't know exactly about yours because your emulator or app settings may be differ.

I recommend you to use [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) in order to make your phone number output in same format.

And, please check [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6003628/361100) also.

Answer (score 0):

As given by @Youngjae, If you want to have formatting then you could try PhoneNumberUtils.

If you want to remove all the formatting then try String.replaceAll as given below.

```
number.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

That will remove all special characters and brackets.